# commenting module creating strange error

Tags: error, comments

Can anyone help with the following error from the commenting feature?
When I want to look at the list of comments in the control panel this is what I get
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with our database.
I deleted the comment entry in the database and that fixed the problem. I think it was an issue of deleting an entry and the comment wasn't also deleted. I'm really not sure exactly what it was though.